# Is it possible to immediately update a date / time with the eonasdan Bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using the [eonasdan Bootstrap datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker) version 4.17.37.  It works fine except that when a year is chosen via the calendar GUI the corresponding date / time in the text control is not updated, until the both the month and day are also chosen.  Is it possible to immediately update the text control when a year is chosen?  I could not see any such option in the documentation.